# Appending a to-do list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a "to do list" app. I am trying to append what I put in the input into a list under "To Do" with a "Done" button. Here is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" text="text/css" href="doneit.css">
        <head>
            <script     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
            </script>
        </head>
  <body>
        <div id="container">
             <input type="text" id="task" placeholder="New Task"/>
                <button id="enter">Enter</button>
                    <div class="todo">
                        <ul id="chores"><h2>To Do:</h2></ul>
                    </div>
                <button id="reset">New List</button>
        </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="doneit.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(
 function() {

var chores=[];

$("#enter").click(function () {
    var task = $("#task").val();
    var $btn = $('<button />', {
        id: "check",
        type: "button",
        text: "Done",
        value: task,
        click: function(){
            var did = this.value;
            $("#todo").append('<p>'+  check+'</p>');
            chores.push(check); 
        }
    });


$(".reset").click(function() {
    location.reload();

});
```

Comment: And the problem/question is?

Comment: Your div has a class of `todo` but you are using the id selector in your JS

Comment: Your markup is invalid. `<h2>` is not a valid child element of `<ul>`

Comment: classes and id's have different selectors

Comment: Learn to use your browser console to check for errors thrown

Comment: it wasn't showing any errors though, I was wondering why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few bugs in your code and it's not exactly clear the output you want to achieve. I had to change some stuff, but you can do something like this and use it as a base.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <input type="text" id="task" placeholder="New Task"/>
    <button id="enter">Enter</button>
    <div class="todo">
        <ul id="chores">To Do:</ul>
    </div>
    <button id="reset">New List</button>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var chores = [];

$("#enter").click(function () {

    var task = $("#task").val();

    var btn = $('<button/>',
            {
                text: "Done",
                value: task,
                click: function () {
                    alert('clicked');
                }
            });

    $("#chores").append('<li>');
    $("#chores").append(task);
    $("#chores").append(btn);
    $("#chores").append('</li>');

    chores.push(task);
});

$("#reset").click(function () {

    $("#chores").empty();
    chores = [];
});
```

Some important notes:

- Understand the difference between $(.class) vs $(#id)
- You should not have more than one element with the same id
- Follow charlietfl advice; the console is your friend
- Use an IDE or validate your markup online
- You don't need to reload the page to clear your list

Answer (score 0):

In your JavaScript code, you are using a non-extant variable named `check`, while you should be using `did` or `this.value`. Also, seems that you don't insert your newly created button anywhere, so the user won't be able to click it.